# Why is my change calculator only working sometimes for some numbers

Tags: python

It only works with certain numbers and I'm not sure why. for example the number 69 works but the number 42 doesn't

```
#Variables
quarter = 25
dime = 10
nickel = 5
penny = 1
money = 0

#Ask user for input
money = int(input("How much change do you need to make?"))

#Get the floor of the money to find how many coins you need and get the remainder and use it as the new amount of money for the next type of coin 
change_quarter = money // quarter
change_quarter_remainder = money % quarter

change_dime = change_quarter_remainder // dime
change_dime_remainder = money % dime

change_nickel = change_dime_remainder // nickel
change_nickel_remainder = money % nickel

change_penny = change_nickel_remainder // penny
change_penny_remainder = money % penny

#Print to the user
print(change quarter, "quarter(s)", change dime, "dime(s)", change nickel, "nickel(s)", change penny, "pennie(s)")
```

Comment: switch everything with suffix _remainder to money and it will work

Comment: You never change money during calculations

Comment: Your method does not work because the dime does not fit evenly into the quarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables with `_remainder` are redundant.

```
change_quarter = money // quarter
money = money % quarter

change_dime = money // dime
money = money % dime

change_nickel = money // nickel
money = money % nickel

change_penny = money
```

Your solution with fix to make it clearer.

```
change_quarter = money // quarter
change_quarter_remainder = money % quarter

change_dime = change_quarter_remainder // dime
change_dime_remainder = change_quarter_remainder % dime

change_nickel = change_dime_remainder // nickel
change_nickel_remainder = change_dime_remainder % nickel

change_penny = change_nickel_remainder // penny
change_penny_remainder = change_nickel_remainder % penny
```

Comment: I'm not sure how or why that fixed it but thanks

Comment: @Pepinallo11 Alternatively use your previous `*_remainder` variables instead of `money`. You were using the original amount each time instead of the updated one with change removed

Comment: Updated the question maybe that will make it clearer